# Как передать список в класс в Python 3.8.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Math:
    def __init__(self,liste):
        self.weight=liste

    def find_max_in_list(self):
        self.weight=list(set(self.weight))
        self.weight=list(reversed(self.weight))
        return self.weight[0]

liste=[1,3,2,5,4,1,6,8,9,10]
example1=Math()
example1.find_max_in_list(liste)
print(example1)
```

Надо было найти максимум в листе но не могу передать значение в `Class Math`

Comment: Надо было найти максимум в листе но не могу передать значение в Class Math ;/

Comment: `return max(self.liste)`?

Comment: а да точно, спасибо ! :) блин только в класс лист не могу закинуть ;/

Answer (score 4):

`liste` надо передавать во время создания класса

```
class Math:
    def __init__(self,liste):
        self.weight=liste

    def find_max_in_list(self):
        self.weight=list(set(self.weight))
        self.weight=list(reversed(self.weight))
        return self.weight[0]

liste=[1,3,2,5,4,1,6,8,9,10]
example1=Math(liste)
example1.find_max_in_list()
print(example1)
```

Comment: Скорее всего будет так: `print(example1.find_max_in_list())`